# Is it possible to place a port on a layer so that it is invisible when the layer.visible is set to false?

Tags: port, layer, visible, gojs

Is it possible to place a port on a layer so that it is invisible when the layer is not visible?
I could not find an answer in GOJS documentation. I tested with this link template and it did not work.

```
myDiagram.linkTemplate =
        $(CustomLink,  // defined below
          { layerName: "blue",...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only put **Part**s in **Layer**s -- either **Node**s or **Link**s or **Adornment**s.  In other words, you cannot split up a Node so that a piece of it appears in one layer and another piece of the same Node appears in a different layer.

The normal thing to do is to show or hide pieces such as ports, either by changing their **visible** property or their **opacity** property.  The former causes the node's panels to be remeasured and rearranged; the latter does not.  Several samples demonstrate this, including the Flow Chart sample.